# Why is CSS background property being cancelled out?

Tags: css

I've looked in Firebug but can't find why a CSS background property is being cancelled out. I've looked if there is a more specific rule but nothing. Please find the image snippet, as follows:

[image]

Maybe somebody has a suggestion?

Comment: Are you sure you do not have another property set, such as background-color oder background-position?

Comment: How can we see what's canceling it out without seeing the rest of the stylesheet?

Answer (score 0):

Firebug will make you think a shorthand property like `background` or `margin` (maybe `font`) was cancelled out when in fact only one property was modified by a later/more specific rule

Use the **Computed** tab (close to the Style one) to see what's going on.

For each individual property, you'll be able to see  which one is more specific and which ones were defined somehow but are cancelled out for real.
It may be a rule with `!important` modifier for example (meh) or usually a `margin-top` over a `margin` and the 3 other properties still with the values set by `margin`.

[image]